# Bootstrap typeahead avoid other value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

i still try in rails 3.2 to use bootstrap typeahead, it works fine, but how can i avoid users to type anything in text field.
I code looks like this

```
<%= text_field_tag(:text, "", :data => {:provide => "typeahead", :items=>"4", :source=>'["Swiss","German","English"]'}) %>
```

users may only type Swiss, German and English in the text field, but not for example Chinese.
How can i validate the value in text field?

Answer (score 0):

Set tag attribute disabled="disabled"

Comment: why disabled? the users should might write something in text field?